# How to move a lastmodifiedfile from a folder to other folder in java?

Tags: java

*I am trying to move the last modified file from a folder to other folder in java. I am able to do last modify but unable to move it to other folder*

```
private File getLatestFilefromDir(String dirPath){
File dir = new File(dirPath);
File[] files = dir.listFiles();
if (files == null || files.length == 0) {
    return null;
}

File lastModifiedFile = files[0];
for (int i = 1; i < files.length; i++) {
   if (lastModifiedFile.lastModified() < files[i].lastModified()) {
       lastModifiedFile = files[i];
   }
}
return lastModifiedFile;
```

}

Comment: Could you please read [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/moving-file-one-directory-another-using-java/) and try to  write some code then share here.

Answer (score 0):

When you get your lastModified file, just use this to copy to another folder:

```
File dest = new File("path/to/file");
FileUtils.copyDirectory(lastModifiedFile, dest);
```

import is `import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;`

Comment: FileUtils.copyDirectory(lastModifiedFile, dest);                                                           
the returntype if file but i have to give file path as source

Comment: what? return type of **FileUtils.copyDirectory()** is void, you pass two File class instances: one for your lastModified and the other with path to copy. what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Import this:

```
import java.io.*; 
import java.nio.file.Files; 
import java.nio.file.*;
```

And here you go:

```
private File getLatestFilefromDir(String dirPath) throws IOException{
    File dir = new File(dirPath);
    File[] files = dir.listFiles();
    if (files == null || files.length == 0) {
        return null;
    }

    File lastModifiedFile = files[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < files.length; i++) {
       if (lastModifiedFile.lastModified() < files[i].lastModified()) {
           lastModifiedFile = files[i];
       }
    }
    String newFilePath = "C:\\newPath\\"+lastModifiedFile.getName();
    Path temp = Files.move 
            (Paths.get(dirPath), 
            Paths.get(newFilePath )); 

            if(temp != null) 
            { 
                System.out.println("File renamed and moved successfully"); 
            } 
            else
            { 
                System.out.println("Failed to move the file"); 
            } 
     return new File(newFilePath );
    }
```

Comment: We don't want to move the whole `dirPath`.

Comment: yes, that is right. i think i am returning the File object.